# How to deserialize JSON when response object can be a list OR a single object

Tags: c#, deserialization

I am sending a API request to an endpoint and receiving a response.

I have an object `RootResponse` This object is never a list and will always be a single object.

Within this object is an object called `Package` and within that, an object called `Activity`.

This activity object represents the information when a carrier scans a package. However sometimes there may be only 1 scan on a package in which case when I deserialize my JSON response into my `RootResponse` object i get the following error

```
Batchtracker.Models.TrackingAPI.Response.Activity[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type
```

I have tried changing the type of object `Activity` to a `List<Activity>` and `Activity[]` but still an error. I understand that the issue is that when there is only one activity scan, it's only returning as a single object and not an array. How can i fix this issue?

Here is an example of the response activity object before deserialization when there is only one scan

```
"Activity": {
  "ActivityLocation": {
    "Address": {
      "CountryCode": "US"
    }
  },
  "Status": {
    "Type": "M",
    "Description": "Order Processed: Ready for UPS",
    "Code": "MP"
  },
  "Date": "20190426",
  "Time": "135618"
},
```

and heres the entire response for any curious

```
{
  "TrackResponse": {
    "Response": {
      "ResponseStatus": {
        "Code": "1",
        "Description": "Success"
      },
      "TransactionReference": ""
    },
    "Shipment": {
      "InquiryNumber": {
        "Code": "01",
        "Description": "ShipmentIdentificationNumber",
        "Value": "redacted"
      },
      "ShipperNumber": "redacted",
      "ShipmentAddress": [{
        "Type": {
          "Code": "01",
          "Description": "Shipper Address"
        },
        "Address": {
          "AddressLine": "redacted redacted redacted redacted",
          "City": "redacted",
          "StateProvinceCode": "GA",
          "PostalCode": "redacted",
          "CountryCode": "US"
        }
      }, {
        "Type": {
          "Code": "02",
          "Description": "ShipTo Address"
        },
        "Address": {
          "City": "redacted",
          "StateProvinceCode": "redacted",
          "PostalCode": "redacted",
          "CountryCode": "US"
        }
      }],
      "ShipmentWeight": {
        "UnitOfMeasurement": {
          "Code": "LBS"
        },
        "Weight": "2.00"
      },
      "Service": {
        "Code": "003",
        "Description": "UPS Ground"
      },
      "ReferenceNumber": {
        "Code": "01",
        "Value": "redacted"
      },
      "PickupDate": "20190426",
      "DeliveryDetail": {
        "Type": {
          "Code": "03",
          "Description": "Scheduled Delivery"
        },
        "Date": "20190430"
      },
      "Package": {
        "TrackingNumber": "redacted",
        "PackageServiceOption": {
          "Type": {
            "Code": "010",
            "Description": "Hundredweight"
          }
        },
        "Activity": {
          "ActivityLocation": {
            "Address": {
              "CountryCode": "US"
            }
          },
          "Status": {
            "Type": "M",
            "Description": "Order Processed: Ready for UPS",
            "Code": "MP"
          },
          "Date": "20190426",
          "Time": "135618"
        },
        "PackageWeight": {
          "UnitOfMeasurement": {
            "Code": "LBS"
          },
          "Weight": "2.00"
        },
        "ReferenceNumber": {
          "Code": "01",
          "Value": "redacted"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I hate APIs that do that. Are you in control of the API to change it? The return value should have a consistent structure. Otherwise, I think your only option is to parse individual values instead of deserializing the whole thing into an object.

Comment: Unfortunately no it's UPS api :\ I wonder if their response in XML is any difference.

Comment: Do a quick search of the json string before you deserialize it, to see if the Activity object is there and has data

Comment: The object does have data.

Comment: What library are you using to deserialize json?

Comment: This is a very complex object. What are you trying to deserialize this into?

Comment: I am using newtonsoft . I generated classes using jsonToCsharp. The response is being deserialized into my RootResponse object.

Comment: Just running quickly this json through the jsontocsharp I can see that the representation is not what I would like. For example it created Type, Type2, Type3 classes, when in fact this would be a List<Type>, I think you would have to analyze the classes carefully and make sure that the classes match the objects. Maybe check documentation to see if they have class structure you need.

Comment: I saw that as well and did not create Type2, Type3, I left it as Type as they are the same objects.

Comment: There is a very good answer to this problem in the answer that itsme86 tagged. Thank you.